# Avoiding selecting pictures on Google captcha I am not a robot

Tags: captcha

On some websites that I access frequently, I get a Google checkbox saying I am not a robot. On some occasions, it requests me to choose pictures of rivers or trees as an additional step on some occasions. Is it possible to bypass this step. I am a human being trying to access the site and not a computer programme. What can I do to convince Google about this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does new Google reCAPTCHA work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27286232/how-does-new-google-recaptcha-work)

Answer (score 0):

There could be several reasons for this captcha to prevent you from accessing websites. You may have some malware/virus/trojan installed on your pc or there are some unusual traffic from your network. You can check you system and network. If you want to "bypass" you can try any proxy sites to access these websites.

Comment: Thanks, Prashant. The captcha does not prevent me from accessing websites. It just makes me follow the additional step of selecting images which I would like to avoid. Is there any way of doing that?