# How to retrieve reCAPTCHA token from iframe with Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, electron, puppeteer, recaptcha, screen-scraping

I'm writing a bot with which I am trying to scrape a reCAPTCHA token after a task has been completed. I'm trying to use:

```js
await page.evaluate(() => document.getElementById('recaptcha-token').value)
```

after the captcha has loaded onto the page, however each time I've been getting the same error: `Uncaught (in promise) Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null`.

I believe that this error is in part caused by the fact that the element that I'm trying to fetch is of type hidden:

```html
<input type="hidden" id="recaptcha-token value="[very long string of letters and numbers]">
```

How would I go about bypassing this?

Answer (score 6):

Firstly I really recommend you to read [Thomas Dondorf's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55500565/12412595) on Puppeteer + reCAPTCHA topic.

If you are still willing to go this way then read my answer below:

---

The fact the `<input>` is `type=hidden` is not affecting how puppeteer interacts with the element as it is already in the DOM. You can even test it from Chrome DevTools *Console* tab by running `$('#recaptcha-token').value`: you will get its value without any problems. In fact the problem lies somewhere else.

Your are facing currently two issues:

1.) The **reCAPTCHA is inside an `iframe` you need to step inside** to let Puppeteer interact with the desired element. To achieve this you will need to grab the exact iframe by its element handle, then using [contentFrame()](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v3.3.0&show=api-elementhandlecontentframe) to switch from "browser" to "frame" context.

2.) You will also need the following **security disabling args** to launch puppeteer: `args: ['--disable-web-security', '--disable-features=IsolateOrigins,site-per-process']` because due to the same-origin policy you are not allowed to go inside the iframe by default.

Example reCAPTCHA page: https://patrickhlauke.github.io/recaptcha/

**Example script:**

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

async function getToken() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    args: ['--disable-web-security', '--disable-features=IsolateOrigins,site-per-process']
  })
  const page = await browser.newPage()

  try {
    await page.goto('https://patrickhlauke.github.io/recaptcha/')

    await page.waitForSelector('.g-recaptcha > div > div > iframe')
    const elementHandle = await page.$('.g-recaptcha > div > div > iframe')
    const frame = await elementHandle.contentFrame()
    const value = await frame.evaluate(() => document.getElementById('recaptcha-token').value)
    console.log(value)
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
  }

  await browser.close()
}
getToken()
```