# Unable to scrape despite IP rotation

Tags: node.js, playwright

I need to scrape this page (the ads): https://www.sahibinden.com/en/cars/used?date=1day&a5_min=2005&a5_max=2020

When I open it too many times I get blocked, changing the IP doesn't help either. The problem is that when I open this page from browser from my PC it works just fine. But it seems to get blocked from webkit.

```
await page.route("**/*", (route) => {
    if (!firstReq) route.continue();
    else {
      firstReq = false;
      route.continue({
        method: method,
        postData: data,
        headers: headers,
      });
    }
  });
  let pageRes = await page.goto(url);
  await page.waitForNavigation()
  await page.unroute("**/*");
  return pageRes;
```

I realize that it is site trying to block bots but what are the practices to avoid that. I have tried waits, ip rotation as well as useragent rotation - nothing seems to be working

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deal with the captcha when doing Web Scraping in Puppeteer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55493536/how-to-deal-with-the-captcha-when-doing-web-scraping-in-puppeteer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In their *[Terms of Use](https://www.sahibinden.com/sozlesmeler/kullanim-kosullari-35)* §4.11 they state that it is not allowed to scrape their content:

> The use of the whole or any part of the "Portal" for [...] Automatic program on the site, robot, spider,
> web crawler , spider, data mining, data crawling etc. "screen
> scraping" software or systems, using automated tools or manual
> processes, [...] such uses will be prevented at the discretion of the OWNER. [...]

So you can be sure they are doing their best to prevent scraping.

There are methods to workaround the blocks, I advise you to read [Thomas Dondorf's great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55500565/12412595) on the topic of headless browsers and blocking by reCaptcha. I also strongly recommend to consider his first option in the current case:

> Option 1: Stop crawling or try to use an official API. As the owner of
> the page does not want you to crawl that page, you could simply
> respect that decision and stop crawling. Maybe there is a documented
> API that you can use.

---

In general there can be huge differences in scraper recognition between visiting the site in headless vs headful mode, using `slowMo` option of [`launch()`](https://playwright.dev/#version=v1.1.1&path=docs%2Fapi.md&q=browsertypelaunchoptions) or not.