# waitForSelector on id AND class*=?

Tags: javascript, node.js, css-selectors, puppeteer

FYI This is in a script being run by puppeteer.
Note: Just updated the css tag and changed it to await bframe.$...

Can anyone tell me the right way to make this match a selector that has "recaptcha-verify-button" who's class list includes "rc-button-disabled" ?

```
await bframe.waitForSelector('button[id="recaptcha-verify-button"]');
```

The selector above works to identify the button but I can't figure out how to include the classlist filter. I believe this would normally do it...

```
 el.classList.contains('rc-button-default-disabled')
```

This is the element I'm trying to identify which is added to the DOM after the initial load.

```
<div class="verify-button-holder">
 <button class="rc-button-default goog-inline-block rc-button-default-disabled" title="" value="" id="recaptcha-verify-button" disabled="">Verify</button>
</div>
```

NOTE: I have tried this which works to get the element BUT it matches on ID and ANY css element, when it should match on the ID AND the css element.

```
await bframe.$('button#recaptcha-verify-button.rc-button-default-disabled');
```

Comment: `'button[id="recaptcha-verify-button"].rc-button-disabled'`

Comment: Also you don't need the `id=`, just `'#recaptcha-verify-button.rc-button-disabled'`

Comment: @Pointy It just ignore's the .rc-... part completely. If I change it to await bframe.$('button[id="recaptcha-verify-button"].asdfasrcasdfasdfsaf'); it still matches.

Comment: FYI - It's a node script that I'm running with puppeteer

Comment: The HTML you added uses the class `rc-button-default-disabled`, not `rc-button-disabled`. Does `rc-button-disabled` get applied later via JS?

Comment: BTW, recaptcha is a tool sites use to prevent webscraping and other forms of automation. Make sure you're aware of this since you're using puppeteer

Comment: @Samathingamajig Yes aware of that.

Comment: @Samathingamajig It doesn't matter what CSS selector I add in there it just gets ignored and always matches on the ID only, not the ID AND the class as "must have both".

Comment: Obligatory: [puppeteer-extra-plugin-recaptcha](https://github.com/berstend/puppeteer-extra/tree/master/packages/puppeteer-extra-plugin-recaptcha)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deal with the captcha when doing Web Scraping in Puppeteer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55493536/how-to-deal-with-the-captcha-when-doing-web-scraping-in-puppeteer)

Answer (score 2):

Just use normal CSS selector syxtax:

- `#` == id
- `.` == class

```js
await bframe.waitForSelector('button#recaptcha-verify-button.rc-button-disabled');
// or with the class that's actually there (rc-button-default-disabled)
await bframe.waitForSelector(`button#recaptcha-verify-button.rc-button-default-disabled`);
```

```js
const myButton = document.querySelector(`button#recaptcha-verify-button.rc-button-default-disabled`);

console.log(myButton);
console.log(myButton.innerText);
```

```html
<div class="verify-button-holder">
 <button class="rc-button-default goog-inline-block rc-button-default-disabled" title="" value="" id="recaptcha-verify-button" disabled="">Verify</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Nope doesn't work it just gets ignored. I will paste the element I'm trying to match into my question above.

Comment: Based off of the [Puppeteer docs](https://devdocs.io/puppeteer/index#framewaitforselectorselector-options), it uses normal CSS queries when using `.waitForSelector`, so this should work

Comment: When I try the document.querySelector code inside await page.evaluate(() => {}); it is returning null with this error...

Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of null