# Re-Captchas and non-headless Puppeteer

Tags: puppeteer, recaptcha, chromium

I am using Puppeteer with non-headless and somehow I keep getting flagged as a bot by Re-Captcha. I'm not trying to do anything shady, I just have some special automation software that's why I use non-headless Chromium.

When I hit a Re-Captcha on Chrome usually I just have to click I am not a bot and it auto verifies me. However, the same does not work in Chromium, they ask for a very complicated captcha, then after that I'm flagged as a bot by the service provider I am using, even though I am non-headless.

I tried `puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth` but I think it only works for headless actually? Is there something similar for non-headless.

Comment: I am pretty sure that you can use the stealth plugin in headful (non-headless) mode. see an example from their Github project: [link](https://github.com/berstend/puppeteer-extra/blob/master/packages/puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth/stealthtests/headful-chromium-stealth.js).

Comment: @theDavidBarton in that case it's not really working :( I still seem to be flagged as a bot even though I'm not really doing anything wrong. It's not my IP since if I just use regular Chrome it works fine, I can't really figure out what the issue is

Comment: yeah, plugin-stealth isn't almighty unfortunately (or luckily). many sites are able to identify automated visits even from headful mode. just an idea: if you can agree with the owner of the site and ensure them that you are doing unharmful visits on their site with puppeteer they may let you through with a custom user agent etc. I recommend you Thomas Dondorf's evergreen answer on captcha (option 1 is for you) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55493536/how-to-deal-with-the-captcha-when-doing-web-scraping-in-puppeteer/55500565#55500565