# How to select a div within a nested div's using beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am not able to get to the div within so many nested divs.
.
.
.

```
<div class="list-card-price">$2,600/mo</div>
```

.
.
.

I am using this method to retrive it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import lxml

response = requests.get(url="https://www.zillow.com/homes/for_rent/1-_beds/?.....")
data = response.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(data,"lxml")

price_list = []

price_tag = soup.select_one(name='div',class_="list-card-price")
print(price_tag)
```

Answer (score 1):

#### What happens?

1. Always take a deeper look into your `soup` - There is the truth! It comes up with a captcha warning.
2. Your selection will throw an error cause you mix syntax of `find()` and `select_one()`

#### How to fix?

1. Take a closer look at this answer [options to deal with captcha](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55500565/14460824)
2. Change your selection to `soup.select_one('div.list-card-price')` to avoid the error `TypeError: select_one() missing 1 required positional argument: 'selector'`

Answer (score 0):

You can check the HTML that's being sent in the soup with "*soup.text*". When I ran the code, the website presented a captcha page to the requests module, not the actual webpage.