# Google reCaptcha version 2 inconsistently showing images

Tags: recaptcha

We just pushed up a form with reCaptcha version 2 so that users don't have to pick images.  The behavior is inconsistent; some users on mac / chrome don't see the images but the same user on safari mac is forced to pick images.

A user on windows / chrome is forced to pick the images.  We can't really determine why some users are seeing images while others are not.  Per the instructions we have, it should just be the site id being associated to a version 2 account that is set as checkbox only.

For reference, [here](https://www.frenchtoast.com/contact-us) is the page.

Comment: Firefox blocks that link telling it is a security risk. In general Google reChaptcha is known to use information google have about the user from all the tracking they do on users to help detect if they need to show images. We who by default block all tracking by google have to pick images every time someone use reCaptcha

Comment: I deselected prevent cross site tracking in safari preferences and yet I still get the pictures in safari?

Comment: Take a look at the answers on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27286232/how-does-google-recaptcha-v2-work-behind-the-scenes?rq=1, it seems like google need to track what you do on internet for a while before you stop getting pictures. On chrome users often are logged in to a google account without even knowing, so easier for google to know if it is a real user.