# Google Recaptcha, How to use the "I'm not a Robot" Captcha instead of the Number/Letter captcha?

Tags: captcha, recaptcha

I implemented Google ReCaptcha into my website but I get the annoying Number/Letter Captcha, I don't want my customers to deal with them out.

I saw on a lot of websites a different Recaptcha from Google where you only have to check a box with the text "I'm not a robot". I would much rather use this since it's much more user-friendly. Now I don't see an option to select this on the Google Recaptcha admin site.

Can someone help me how to enable the "I'm not a Robot" Recaptcha ?

Answer (score 3):

The captcha in question is a beta and is only allowed use if you are in the beta program here is a link that I found: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js

Also, you may want to look at this thread:[How does this checkbox recaptcha work and how can I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25545514/how-does-this-checkbox-recaptcha-work-and-how-can-i-use-it)